# Styling for HTML5 element disappears in IE10 & IE11 when dev tools (F12) is opened

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-10, modernizr, internet-explorer-11

Because of the nature of the system I am working on, I cannot share code or screen shots.

I have built a HTML5 prototype for my company, it utilizes LESS compiled CSS, and modernizr. It looks good cross browser, until you open the dev tools in IE10 & IE11, at that point all the styling that refers to the header tag, disappears. This issues does not happen in IE7, IE8 or IE9.

Has anyone come across anything like this? I'm not sure where to even start trying to fix it.

Comment: is it possible you are hitting a media-query becuase the screen size is changing when you open the dev tools? do the styles reappear when you shrink the dev tools down very small?

Comment: I have not implemented any media-queries yet. Style does not come back when the screen gets larger.

Comment: unfortunately not much anyone can do to help without code, then. I would suggest you start removing the javascript and css files one by one until you are able to determine when it does NOT happen, and post more information about that.

Comment: As soon as I have time to come back to this (off on another hot bug now) then I will finish the codepen.io I am working on to prove my theory. I will share the results here.

Comment: looking forward to it!

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I too am facing the same issue and it only occurs with F12 tools open on page load or opening F12 tools after the page has been loaded. We are not using media queries on this page...yet and its only this one page. After reading thru all the JS and CSS I do not see any issues which could be caused by F12 tools. Going to try to systematically remove files. I'll update if I find an exact cause as well.